# как правильно вычесть разность дат на java

Tags: java, дата, calendar

Как правильно вычесть разность дат на Java, что б показывал разницу в часа и минутах 24:00? Я пробовал написать программу но у меня получается 23:59.

```
package mycalc;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
public class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    final private JSpinner sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4;
    final private JTextField jtf;
    private Date d1, d2;
    private Long max, min;
    private Calendar time;

    MyListener(JSpinner sp1, JSpinner sp2, JSpinner sp3, JSpinner sp4,
            JTextField jtf) {
        this.sp1 = sp1;
        this.sp2 = sp2;
        this.sp3 = sp3;
        this.sp4 = sp4;
        this.jtf = jtf;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        d1 = (Date) sp1.getValue();
        d2 = (Date) sp2.getValue();

        max = Math.max(d1.getTime(), d1.getTime());
        min = Math.min(d2.getTime(), d2.getTime());
        time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        time.clear();
        time.setTimeInMillis(max - min);

        long t3 = time.getTimeInMillis();

        long msec = t3 % 1000;
        t3 = t3 / 1000;
        long sec = t3 % 60;
        t3 = t3 / 60;
        long min = t3 % 60;
        t3 = t3 / 60;
        long hour = t3;

        // делаем удобочитаемую строку
        String res = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
        System.out.println(res);

    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете перевести всё в timestamp, вычесть, а потом вернуть обратно.

Comment: Спасибо большое , Очень помогло , через LocalDateTime и Duration всё сделал как нужно )))

Comment: Тогда ответьте на свой вопрос и выделите его верным, чтобы закрыть вопрос.